# Grails 2.4.4 Intellij debug mode

Tags: debugging, grails, intellij-14

hi i had an issue when i run the application on debug mode, seems that does not load all plugins required and i get this error.

`No suitable driver found for jdbc:teradata://DatabaseURL`

I tried to modify fork on configuration file if i uncomment and run

`grails.project.fork = [
      run: [maxMemory:2048, minMemory:64, debug:true, maxPerm:512]
]`

the application never loads and keep listening a socket

```
|Environment set to development .................................  
|Packaging Grails application .............................................................  
|Running Grails application  
   Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
```

Comment: What database are you trying to connect? Make sure you have proper driver for it. What configuration file did you uncommented?

Comment: Does it work when you don't debug?

Comment: yes it woks, when i don't run in debug, the driver works when i run the application but when i run debug mode every thing work until i want to use teradata database to get some information.